# ansible ad-hoc command to check variable that's in ansible vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I'm trying to check what value Ansible pulls for the variable `datadog_agent_api_key` that is currently stored in Ansible Vault file `inventory/common/vault-common-vars.yml`.

```
ansible myhost.domain.com -i inventory/hosts.ini --connection=local -m debug -a var=datadog_agent_api_key --include_vars=inventory/common/vault-common-vars.yml
```

When I run it, I am getting the error

```
ansible: error: unrecognized arguments: --include_vars=inventory/common/vault-common-vars.yml
```

If the variable is not in Ansible Vault, it pulls the value correctly.

```
ansible myhost.domain.com -i inventory/hosts.ini --connection=local -m debug -a var=datadog_agent_system_probe_enabled

myhost.domain.com | SUCCESS => {
    "datadog_agent_system_probe_enabled": true
```

What's the proper options to use or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

include_vars is a module not an option.

if you want to see the content of a vault file use:

```
ansible-vault view  nameoffile --ask-vault-pass
```

the option `--ask-vault-pass`  -> a prompt to ask the password of encrypted file

if you want to launch from a command line use:

```
ansible localhost -m include_vars -a file=inventory/common/vault-common-vars.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: I'm trying to verify that a host is pulling the correct variable when the playbook runs. I already know how to view the vault.

Comment: @BillKe  if you want to launch from a command line use my answer modifed